# CSS @media only screen and(max-width: 800px) no funciona

Tags: html, css, responsive, mediaqueries

Estoy practicando diseño responsive y estoy tratando de aplicarselo a este pedazo de codigo de HTML:

```html
<div class="caja1">
            <h1>Este es el titulo de la pagina</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis ducimus placeat eaque eum tempora voluptatibus aliquam tenetur at iure neque expedita, vero numquam doloremque exercitationem quisquam ipsum, beatae earum vitae?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="caja2">
            <h1>Titulo de noticia</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique quibusdam, asperiores, laboriosam dignissimos harum ipsam inventore perspiciatis aspernatur magni quaerat officia a, tempora ut necessitatibus quam et explicabo quidem qui!</p>
        </div>
```

Y este codigo en CSS:

```css
@media  only screen and (max-width: 800px){

div{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

Aca el meta viewport que utilice:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Lei en otro post que intente sin utilizar `only` pero seguía sin funcionar

Tengo la sensación de que no me estaria tomando `only` y `and` pero no se como solucionarlo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A lo que quiero llegar es que cuando tenga menor a 800px:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando sea mayor a 800px:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es la primera vez que hago esta pregunta, Y aunque ponga un espacio, no pasa absolutamente nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .caja1{
        background: #d3d3d3;
    }
    .caja2{
        background: #25b1a9;
    }
    .caja1, .caja2{
        padding: 3% 2% 1.5% 2%; /* el valor de padding lo puedes editar a tu gusto */
    }
    @media (min-width: 800px){
    .container{
    /*display: flex;*/ /* Con flex, elimina grid si deseas usar flex y descomenta esta linea seleccionando todo el texto comentado y presionas la tecla control Ctrl + } */ 
    display: grid; /* Con grid, elimina flex si deseas usar grid */
    grid-template-columns: auto auto; /* Define un ancho automatico dependiendo del numero de elementos en el contenedor, si hubiera un tercer div (caja3), cada caja tendria 33.333333% de ancho */
    }
    .caja1, .caja2{
    /*width: 50%; Define 50% de ancho a cada caja cuando la pantalla tiene un minimo de 800px*/
    }
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="caja1">
            <h1>Este es el titulo de la pagina</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis ducimus placeat eaque eum tempora voluptatibus aliquam tenetur at iure neque expedita, vero numquam doloremque exercitationem quisquam ipsum, beatae earum vitae?</p>
        </div>

       <div class="caja2">
            <h1>Titulo de noticia</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique quibusdam, asperiores, laboriosam dignissimos harum ipsam inventore perspiciatis aspernatur magni quaerat officia a, tempora ut necessitatibus quam et explicabo quidem qui!</p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Creo que @BetaM lo ha explicado muy bien, creas un elemento padre, en este caso un div con clase container y para poner un div al lado de otro, debes definir a su contenedor, display flex o grid (dos mejores formas de hacerlo), con flex, los elementos se ponen al lado del otro, pero en este caso como son dos divs con clase caja1 y caja2, tienen por defecto [display block](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display) , no se pondran al lado del otro porque ocupan todo el ancho, para ponerlos al lado del otro, define un ancho de 50% a cada caja, con grid es un diseño basado en cuadriculas, facilita mucho el diseño web, te recomiendo que practiques [grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) , he dejado por defecto grid, pero si quieres cambiar a flex, en los comentarios que dejo en el css te dicen como.

Answer (score 0):

Comentarios:

- Los **`divs`** ya son elementos de tipo bloque, por tanto la media query que escribiste inicialmente no solo no afectará a dichas etiquetas sino que esta demás (*basándonos en el resultado esperado*) pues cuando el ancho del contenedor sea de 800 o menos los 2 div aparecerán uno debajo del otro

  - Lo que en este punto debes modificar en todo caso es al ancho de cada div, darles color e indicar un centrado horizontal
- Para lograr el acomodo que buscas deberías considerar modificarlos de esta forma:

  - Declara un **`div`** padre que contenga a tus 2 cajas
  - Ahora lo que debes indicar en la media query es que cuando el ancho mínimo sea por ejemplo de 801 pixeles entonces el **`div`** contenedor de las cajas tenga un display de tipo *flex*
- Usamos la opción anterior por que ambos divs pasarán de estar apilados uno encima del otro a estar uno a lado del otro en fila

  - En este punto ya solo te falta estilizar ambos div para lograr el resultado esperado

```html
    <style>
      @media only screen and (min-width: 801px) {
        .cajas {
          display: flex;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <div class="cajas">
      <div class="caja1">
        <h1>Este es el titulo de la pagina</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis ducimus placeat eaque eum tempora voluptatibus aliquam tenetur at iure neque expedita, vero numquam doloremque exercitationem quisquam ipsum, beatae earum vitae?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="caja2">
        <h1>Titulo de noticia</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique quibusdam, asperiores, laboriosam dignissimos harum ipsam inventore perspiciatis aspernatur magni quaerat officia a, tempora ut necessitatibus quam et explicabo quidem qui!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Y en menor medida y sobre la cual no basaré mi respuesta es por ejemplo hacer a los elementos flotar, pero **para este caso** flexbox es a mi parecer una mejor opción.

**Lecturas de interés**

- [Elementos en bloque](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)
- [Módulo de flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar esta otra forma, sin usar inline-block o block como referencia. O se puede usar display: flex o colum-count.

```
@media screen (max-width: 800px) {
 .cajas {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  column-count: 2;
 }
}
```

Comment: Un div debe tener una clase o un id

Comment: Estoy usando un editor móvil. Puede ser que en una PC sea diferente.

Comment: Escribi mal el código. Es @media screen and (mix-width: 800px)